# Calculate GFP Payload FCS

Tags: c, crc32

I'm trying to calculate the payload FCS (pFCS) of a GFP (Generic Framing Procedure) frame and can't get the right value.

What I did was descramble the payload and use CRC32 on the bytes starting from the Payload Header (4-byte PTI, PFI, EXI, UPI, eHEC) to the end of the GFP PDU, excluding the 4-byte pFCS. The CRC32 code I used was taken from [echo47's post](http://www.edaboard.com/thread120700.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char data[] =
  {
    0x00, 0x0A, 0xE6, 0xF0, 0x05, 0xA3, 0x00, 0x12,
    0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x30, 0xB3, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x11,
    0x72, 0xBA, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C,
    0x89, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
    0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D,
    0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13
  };
  unsigned int crc_table[] =
  {
    0x4DBDF21C, 0x500AE278, 0x76D3D2D4, 0x6B64C2B0,
    0x3B61B38C, 0x26D6A3E8, 0x000F9344, 0x1DB88320,
    0xA005713C, 0xBDB26158, 0x9B6B51F4, 0x86DC4190,
    0xD6D930AC, 0xCB6E20C8, 0xEDB71064, 0xF0000000
  };
  unsigned int n, crc=0;

  for (n=0; n<sizeof(data); n++)
  {
    crc = (crc >> 4) ^ crc_table[(crc ^ (data[n] >> 0)) & 0x0F];  /* lower nibble */
    crc = (crc >> 4) ^ crc_table[(crc ^ (data[n] >> 4)) & 0x0F];  /* upper nibble */
  }
  for (n=0; n<4; n++)  /* display the CRC, lower byte first */
  {
    printf("%02X ", crc & 0xFF);
    crc >>= 8;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I was able to use this CRC32 code to get the correct Ethernet FCS, but not the GFP pFCS. The eHEC was also the right value. Am I calculating the pFCS wrongly, or do I need to use a different CRC32 calculation method?

Comment: That's the correct CRC32.  The CRC bytes should be sent most significant first.

Comment: I was seeing completely different byte values from what was calculated using the above algorithm, and what was sent in the GFP frame, not just in the reverse order. Oh, and the data[] above is for the Ethernet frame only, which has the same FCS as the value calculated, not the entire GFP frame.

Comment: Then you are likely applying the CRC algorithm to the incorrect subset of bytes.

Comment: I'm really having trouble figuring this out. Using the example  III.3 provided in the GFP ITU-T G.7041 document, on page 58, it says that the payload FCS is calculated over 28 bytes of payload. I took it to mean Byte 9 to Byte 36, inclusive. However, using the algorithm above, I got the value 0x11ED3040, and not the 0x87648BBB given in the example. What am I missing?

Comment: I get the same thing.  It's possible that the document is in error.  Do you have examples of real transmitted GFP frames?

Comment: I was able to finally get the correct value and posted it as the answer. Apparently due to the order of the bits transmitted, the order of the bits used for calculating the CRC for GFP is in the reverse order compared to Ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get the correct CRC32 value for the GFP frames after using the [CRC calculator code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crccalculator/files/CRC/) and changing `#define REVERSED_DATA` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

I guess I was previously not able to get the correct value because of the order the bits were sent. GFP sends the bits in the opposite direction compared to Ethernet, as mentioned in this [post](http://compgroups.net/comp.dcom.sdh-sonet/differences-between-ethernet-and-gfp-fcs/21153).